# Gridview ItemTemplate with If condition of Database Data

Tags: asp.net, if-statement, gridview

In `GridView` I would like to use show one of 3 result If condition is true show text 1 else if show text 2 else show text 3

i know to use if else for display 2 condition result : `<%#Eval("result").ToString().ToLower().Equals("0") ? "text 1" : "text 2" %>`

But i need check result for three values : 0 and 1 and 2

And show message for each one but i don't know how to do

Like below but i know it is wrong but i need correct model

```
<ItemTemplate>
              <%# If Eval("result")=="0" { %>


                       text 1


              <%# } else If Eval("result")=="1" Then { %>


                       text 2

               <%# }else{ %>

                       text 3

              <%# } %>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

How you tried to use `GridView1_RowDataBound` below is a different example that should work out for you also

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">  
        <div>  
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="6" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">  
                <Columns>  
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id"/>  
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"/>  
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City"/>  
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="Salary" HeaderText="Salary"/>  
                </Columns>  
            </asp:GridView>  
        </div>  
    </form>  


protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)  
    {  
        //Checking the RowType of the Row  
        if(e.Row.RowType==DataControlRowType.DataRow)  
        {  
            //If Salary is less than 10000 than set the row Background Color to Cyan  
            if(Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[3].Text)<10000)  
            {  
                e.Row.BackColor = Color.Cyan;  
            }  
        }  
    }
```